# Internal Server Error: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: . when calling findById, or DeleteById method

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I am trying to create a sample application using micronaut framework.
I have created a repository class that extends JPA repository

```
import com.rest.micronaut.Entity.FileEntity;

import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface FileRepository extends CrudRepository<FileEntity, Long> {
}
```

and using the default methods to save and fetch the data from H2 database.

When I am using save or find all methods I am getting desired results but when using methods like findById, it throws error with message

```
{
"message": "Internal Server Error: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: . near line 1, column 81 [SELECT entity.FileEntity_.id FROM com.rest.micronaut.Entity.FileEntity AS entity.FileEntity_ WHERE (entity.FileEntity_.id = :p1)]"
}
```

Here is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "6.1.0"
id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.2.0"
}

version "0.1"
group "com.rest.micronaut"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.rest.micronaut.*")
     }
 }


dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.8")

    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-hibernate-jpa")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16"
}

mainClassName = "com.rest.micronaut.Application"
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('1.8')
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('1.8')
}
```

here is the link to code repository

> https://github.com/aprabhat/micronaut-restful-sample

Comment: Can you also show FileEntity class?

Comment: @AmitB10 here is the link to FileEntity class,
https://github.com/aprabhat/micronaut-restful-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rest/micronaut/Entity/FileEntity.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your package name - it should be `com.rest.micronaut.entity`, not `com.rest.micronaut.Entity` (similarly `com.rest.micronaut.Model` should be `com.rest.micronaut.model`). Package names should always be lowercase to avoid confusing package names with class and interface names.

My guess is that Hibernate was assuming your class was a static inner class, so the generated HQL/SQL was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. This solves the issue.